# Upgrading to Heroku-20, OpenSSL “dh key too small” workaround with Mechanize

Tags: heroku, openssl, mechanize-ruby

Tried recently to upgrade from Heroku-18 to Heroku-20, and encounted the error described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-20-stack#upgrading-to-heroku-20

I contacted the website that I use Mechanize to automate interaction with, but it's likely it will take them a long time to fix.

I rolled back to Heroku-18 for the time being . But I'm wondering if there is some way to temporarily, or on the fly, workaround the DEFAULT@SECLEVEL issue.

Thanks!